# Resizing SVG but doing it so by editing it's container

Tags: html, css, svg, uikit

I've got an `<a>` with an `<svg>` inside, but the thing is that the svg is coming from uiKit and I can't edit it (it's too small). Is there any way I can make it bigger from the `<a>`?

```
<a class="uk-position-center-left uk-position-small uk-hidden-hover uk-icon uk-slidenav-previous" href="#" uk-slidenav-previous="" uk-slider-item="previous">
            <!-- SVG -->
</a>
<a class="uk-position-center-right uk-position-small uk-hidden-hover uk-icon uk-slidenav-next" href="#" uk-slidenav-next="" uk-slider-item="next">
            <!-- SVG -->
</a>
```

Comment: Add a CSS  scale transform to the <a> element.

Comment: @RobertLongson thanks! I'll try.